How to jump to definitions in different modules using `eglot`
I am using eglot (have tried both pyright and pylsp).
Jumping to definition at point works, but when I select a variable imported from a different package, or the package itself, nothing happens.
For example, import xyz from numpy, I cannot jump to where xyz is defined in the numpy module.
What might I be missing to make this work?
I've been able in some cases to get a message:
"user-error: No definitions found for: LSP identifier at point" that appears the first time, and requesting again does lead to the variable. This applies to numpy/pandas/other public packages, but not to any variable in the project I'm working on.
